# Отслеживание изменения в адресной строке

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как отследить изменение в адресной строке, изменить или удалить из нее часть, и обновить страницу с новым урл?
Зачем нужно. На странице используется AJAX фильтрация, формируя вот такой урл
site.ru/sapogi?page=5&filter=59

Нужно вот эту часть page=ЛЮБАЯ ЦИФРА& привести к виду page=1& или вообще удалить оставив только site.ru/sapogi?filter=59 и обновить страницу с новым урл.

Подскажите как правильно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За url отвечает объект: 
**document.location**

**document.location.href** - Все url ссылка целиком 
**document.location.search** - Get параметры 
**document.location.hash** - Только хеш ссылки (все что идет после знака #)

В вашем случае можно поступить так:

```
var get = document.location.search;
get = get.replace(/page=\d*/gi, "page=1");
document.location.search = get;
```

**1)** Достаем из ссылки часть с GET параметрами 
**2)** Заменяем регуляркой нужное значение 
**3)** Вставляем в url и перезагружаем страницу

Comment: Спасибо. Сам по себе работает, но у меня нет. Видимо нужно на событие повесить, а там видимо очередность соблюдать надо, не срабатывает по клику.